# Excepciones PHP

Tags: php, excepciones

Estaba tratando el tema de Excepciones en PHP, pero me surgio una duda. Para capturar las excepciones debemos nosotros arrojarlas manualmente o recogerlas solamente con un try catch?

```
try{
  $num = 1/0;
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Por ejemplo, aqui realize un division para cero, pero al intentar capturar la Excepcion no lo hace. Debo arrojarla manualmente? Lo pregunto porque si no mal recuerdo en Java creo que este te las capturaba con solo colocar el bloque try.

Comment: Lo estás haciendo bien, pero la división por 0 es un error que dispara una advertencia, no una excepción... Fijate en https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En PHP, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, la división por cero levanta un `E_WARNING`. Según [esta nota del Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php#118928), esto es así por compatibilidad con PHP 5.

Una forma que hacer que la división por cero sea tratada como una Excepción, sería definiendo **en ese contexto** un manejador de errores personalizado mediante el uso de
[`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php). Indicarías una función que maneje los errores de tipo `E_WARNING` y desde dentro de dicha función levantas una `Exception`. Haciendo eso, podrás capturar los `E_WARNING` que levanta la división por cero como si fuesen excepciones. No hay que olvidar, al final, volver el manejo de errores a su configuración original con [`restore_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.restore-error-handler.php).

Por ejemplo<sup>1</sup>:

```
set_error_handler("warning_handler", E_WARNING);

function warning_handler($errno, $errstr) { 
    throw new \Exception($errstr, $errno);
}

try{
  $num = 1/0;
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
# No olvidar restaurar el error_handler
restore_error_handler();
```

### PD

Quizá lo más conveniente sería que escribas tu propia clase de manejo de errores, donde podrás solventar este problema y otros, haciendo que tu manejo de errores en PHP sea parezca a lo que ocurre en otros lenguajes, donde la división por cero por ejemplo, es tratada como una `Exception`.

---

1. Fuente: [Una de las respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206244/5587982) a la pregunta [*Can I try/catch a warning?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241728/5587982) de Stackoverflow en inglés.

Answer (score 3):

Puntos importantes:

- La operación que tratas de hacer arroja un [**WARNING**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php)

  - Por lo tanto la estructura como la propones no será del todo funcional para evaluar el escenario que planteas
- Deberás construir un método en el cual asignes una instancia de la clase `Exception` y evaluar
- La documentación de PHP propone que las excepciones se traten dentro de una estructura de [try - catch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions) de modo que toda posible excepción sea atrapada y manejada

La documentación de PHP [propone un ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.examples) para evaluar precisamente la división de un número por cero.